# I am getting range of cells as input from user and want to traverse it one by one and write data in one of the column

Tags: excel, vba, https

Let's say I have a worksheet like this:

| Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| val 1 | val 4 | output 1 |
| val 2 | val 3 | output 2 |

So user gives range of this and I want to concatenate val 1 and val 4 and I am sending this as API request; now I am getting response and want to store it in column c output 1 .

This is what I have tried but it is not working

```
sub program()
    Dim rng         As Range
    Set rng = Range("A2: C3")
    Dim itr         As Integer
    itr = 0
    Dim msg         As String
    For Each cell In rng
        If itr = 3 Then
            itr = itr + 1
            MsgBox cell.Address
        End If
        
        If itr = 4 Then
         ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range(cell.Address).value = lines(2)
         MsgBox cell.Address
         itr = 0
          
         End If
         
         msg = msg & cell
        itr = itr + 1
        
    Next cell
    
End Sub
```

This is what I wrote - but it doesn't work the way I want it to, and starts behaving out of normal after first row

Comment: You start your iteration at 0 and go up to 3, that's 4 cells your iterating (per what you intend to be a row) but you only have 3 columns per row. - Also the second if statement is just unnecessary, It will always (and only) trigger when the first if statement has triggered, so just put the logic in the 2nd if statement into the first one. Currently your saying If i = 3 then set i = 4 and then check if i = 4 and if it is 4 then do something else. Just skip the 4  and say: if i = 3 do something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are keeping track of a 2D space with one single iteration variable? - how is that supposed to work. If there are 2 dimensions you need 2 variables to reliably keep track of where you are (one for horizontally one for vertically).

I would suggest you put the values of the provided Range into an array

```
Dim dataArray As Variant
dataArray = yourRange.Value
```

With UBound(dataArray) and UBound(dataArray, 2) you now have the dimensions of your array and can traverse it with 2 loops:

```
For i = 1 To UBound(dataArray)
    For j = 1 To UBound(dataArray, 2)
        'your code here (i is current row, j current column Nr.)
    Next j
Next i
```

If you change values in the array you'll just need to do `yourRange.Value = dataArray` when you are finshed to set the values of the range to the values you've put/changed in the array.